# OS Master Map Styling in QGIS using QML/SLD

Tags: qgis, style, ordnance-survey, os-mastermap, qml

I am  trying to apply stylesheet that I downloaded in qml format from GitHub of Ordnance Survey https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-VectorMap-District-stylesheets/tree/master/GML%20stylesheets

Master Map looks fine in the default styling but when I apply the style that I downloaded makes the Map disappear. What could be the reason to make it disappear into QGIS.

Same happens with SLD stylesheet

Below is the screenshot of the attributes of the QML stylesheet

[image]

Comment: What happens if you Zoom in?

Comment: Zoom in or out doesn't help to display the map

Comment: The potential reason for that might be, the distinct fields in the attribute table does not match with the stylesheet attributes, is this something can be a reason, what would be the potential solution?

Comment: You seem to be mixing the data and stylesheets from VecMapLocal and MasterMap which are completely different products and will not match or work

Comment: @iant looking back at this question just now in relation to another OSMM question, I think you comment is the answer isn't it?